# DSRA9110E: Connection is closed

Tags: java, spring, websphere, spring-transactions

I am getting below exception in spring transactional

> Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is
>   com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: Connection
>   is closed.

I am using web sphere connection pool.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/233044/how-to-resolve-dsra9110e-connection-is-closed-exce.html ?

Comment: yes @ChiragParmar. This is not the case. 1 thread completed the transaction and second thread is trying after 15-20 min and its failing.

Comment: So please describe in more details your problem and scenario, as currently it is not enough to diagnose.

Comment: please add a stack trace and some application code that is involved in the call path.  As @Gas said, there is not enough info to provide any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by setting "Minimum connections" to 0. This is not performance-wise but much better than exception.

Comment: You probably should set `Aged timeout` instead of setting minimum connections to 0 (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/udat_conpoolset.html). As in most such cases firewall is killing connections that are opened too long.

Comment: @Gas We have Unused timeout for that (and i really wonder why it does not solve the problem, may be we have to reduce it from 1800 to 1200?) . I don't understand how Aged timeout can help.

Comment: Unused timeout only clears connection down to Minimum count, dont go any further (it would keep some connections forever if min >0, no matter if they are not used), where Aged timeout closes connections older than x, no matter what the minimum pool size is, and no matter of unused timeout. So this is better setting as it allows you to keep min > 0, and protects for stale (too long keep opened).

Comment: Ok, I see. But now I came to conclusion that Aged timeout is useless because it acts exactly as I set Minimum connections to 0 and Unused timeout to value of Aged timeout.

Comment: It is not the same, because if you just set unused timeout, connection may stay open forever if it is constantly used. And in case of aged, it will always be closed, no matter if it is used or not. So the unused timeout doesnt protect you from firewall killing active connections opened for too long time.